# How to redirect form to different url on different button click

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

i am making a blog on Laravel and i am trying to redirect form to different url based on different button click . you can also refer my code

```
<form action="{{url('/storepost')}}" id="submitform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <input type="text" name="blogtitle" placeholder="Enter the blog Title" class="form-control" >
            <textarea class="form-control" id="editor" name="editor" rows="3"></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Publish</button>
            <span><button class="btn btn-warning">Save as Draft</button></span>
        </form>
```

as i have two buttons that is publish and save as draft and i want to redirect the form to different url based on button clicks , i don't understand how to do this .

can anybody help me out on this .

Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

You can submit your form with a name and in the controller check for the name of the input.

```
<form action="{{url('/storepost')}}" id="submitform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <input type="text" name="blogtitle" placeholder="Enter the blog Title" class="form-control" >
            <textarea class="form-control" id="editor" name="editor" rows="3"></textarea>

    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="publish" name="publish" />
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save as Draft" name="draft" /></span>
</form>
```

And in the controller check for the input:

**Controller**

```
if(\request()->has('draft')){
    \\ Do draft
} else {
    \\ Do publish
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you could work around with it
you need to change your button tag to `input:submit` and add a `name="type"` for example
and in your backend, you could check this value

```
<form action="{{url('/storepost')}}" id="submitform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <input type="text" name="blogtitle" placeholder="Enter the blog Title" class="form-control" >
            <textarea class="form-control" id="editor" name="editor" rows="3"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="type" value="Publish">
            <span><input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="type" value="Save as Draft"></span>
        </form>
```

after that in your controller, you could simply check the value like this

```php
public function store(Request $request){
     if($request->input('type') == 'Publish'){
         // do something
     } else {
         // do another thing
     }
}
```